# django change email address - confirm password

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms

I have a form that allows the user to change their email address. The form also prompts the user to enter their current password as part of the form.

The form does change the email address, but the user can enter any value for the password and the email address is changed.

For some reason, the password is not being checked and confirmed before the email is changed.

I cannot figure out what I have done.

Here is my form code:

```
class EmailChangeForm(forms.Form):
error_messages = {
    'email_mismatch': _("The two e-mail address fields do not match."),
    'email_inuse': _("This e-mail address cannot be used. Please select a different e-mail address."),
    'password_incorrect': _("Incorrect password."),
}

current_password = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Current Password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    required=True
)

new_email1 = forms.EmailField(
    label=_("New E-mail Address"),
    max_length=254,
    required=True
)

new_email2 = forms.EmailField(
    label=_("Confirm New E-mail Address"),
    max_length=254,
    required=True
)

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super(EmailChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_current_password(self):
    """
    Validates that the password field is correct.
    """
    current_password = self.cleaned_data["current_password"]
    if not self.user.check_password(current_password):
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['password_incorrect'], code='password_incorrect',)
    return current_password

def clean_new_email1(self):
    """
    Prevents an e-mail address that is already registered from being registered by a different user.
    """
    email1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_email1')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email1).count() > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['email_inuse'], code='email_inuse',)
    return email1

def clean_new_email2(self):
    """
    Validates that the confirm e-mail address's match.
    """
    email1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_email1')
    email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_email2')
    if email1 and email2:
        if email1 != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['email_mismatch'], code='email_mismatch',)
    return email2

def save(self, commit=True):
    self.user.email = self.cleaned_data['new_email1']
    if commit:
        self.user.save()
    return self.user
```

Here is my views.py code:

```
@login_required
def email_change(request):
    language_versions = get_language_versions(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = EmailChangeForm(user=request.user)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('successfully updated.'))
            return redirect('email_change')
    return render(request, 'user_settings/email_change.html', {
        'display_default_language': display_default_language(request.user),
        'form': form,
        'languages': LANGUAGES,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num': len(language_versions),
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clean_password()` method should be called `clean_current_password()`.

Comment: thanks catavan, I edited the code in the post above, but changing the `clean_password(self)` to `clean_current_password(self)` still allows the email change with the incorrect password. Any suggestions?

Comment: Reload the application. I tested the code from your question and it works fine. I got "Incorrect password." message for invalid password and email is changed if I enter the valid password.

Comment: hold the phone - that works! corrected some of the other code. Thanks catavan.